# select sum values on different conditions in sql

Tags: sql, select

This is the table I got in the middle of approaching what I want.

```
Equip unit qty
---------------
a     01    2
a     01    3     
a     09   14
b     01    5
b     09   28
```

I'm trying to find the value 3+14+5+28.

I want to sum all values in different equipment and different unit but if the unit is same, it should be selected the maximum value (in this case, I want to pick 3 instead 2).

I've been struggling to find ways but still have no idea. How would you do solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select sum(qty)
from (select equip, unit, max(qty) as qty
      from t
      group by equip, unit
     ) eu;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/KWJGU24398) is an example in Rextester.

You can also do this without a subquery in the `from`, assuming the maximum is not duplicated:

```
select sum(qty)
from t
where qty = (select max(t2.qty) from t t2 where t2.equip = t.equip and t2.unit = t.unit);
```

Comment: From your first answer, it returns 3+28 = 31. I don't still get it.

Comment: @sunsets . . . No, they work as you specify.  I have put in a link to working code.

Comment: ahhh, I missed something and it works! thanks a lot :) I think i didn't understand group by with two columns. Thanks a lot. It's clear 100% now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT Equipment
        ,Unit
        ,Quantity
        ,Row_Number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Equipment
            ,Unit ORDER BY Quantity DESC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM SampleTable
    )
SELECT Sum(Quantity) AS Total
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: I'm going to comment soon after studying Row_Number() statement!

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the meaning of this code and it works well!

Comment: Glad it helped you. If it helped in any way then don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**--Create table from below script**

```
create table eqip(equip varchar(3), unit int, qty int);
```

**--Insert Record for query for testing**

```
insert into eqip
values('a'  ,  01 ,   2),
('a',     01 ,   3    ) ,
('a'  ,   09 ,  14),
('b'  ,   01 ,   5),
('b' ,    09 ,  28)
```

**--Run below query for getting result. Where Row_Number getting PARTITION by unit and qty.**

```
select sum(qty) as total_quantity from(
    select Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY equip,unit ORDER BY qty DESC) AS row_num, equip, unit, qty from eqip
) as A where row_num=1;
```

Comment: Cheers! I got what you mean! Thanks a lot!